# Is it possible to search YouTube subtitles?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api, subtitle

Suppose I want to find list of videos which have the phrase "French presidential election" in its subtitle.

Can I do this using YouTube API?

It will be perfect if it can even search within both human-generated and auto-generated subtitles. But it will be good enough if it can search either of the two types of subtitles.

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 3):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions). You can use [`Captions: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list) which returns a list of caption tracks that are associated with a specified video.

*Note that the API response does not contain the actual captions and that the [`captions.download`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) method provides the ability to retrieve a caption track.*

You need to provide the `videoId` parameter that specifies the YouTube video ID of the video for which the API should return caption tracks.

Here's a related thread: [How to add Subtitles to Youtube video using Youtube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770814/how-to-add-subtitles-to-youtube-video-using-youtube-api)

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is how to search through ALL videos for particular words

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just search the subtitles from a particular video that is open on youtube.com you can view all the subtitles by selecting 'Open Transcript' from the `...` button which is displayed below the main video window and to the right of the title (to the right of `SAVE`) - then you can just search them using the browser's page search functionality (i.e. Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, Win: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is how to search through ALL videos for particular words